# What does Neil mean by "In a parallel worlds theory, we can't know the relationship between consciousness and multiple realities"?

Tags: tenet

In *Tenet*, the Protagonist and Neil had this conversation, just after discussing the [grandfather paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox) (emphasis mine):

> Protagonist: This reversing the flow of time. Doesn't us being here now mean it never happens? That we stop them?
> Neil: Optimistically, I'd say that's right.
> Protagonist: Pessimistically?
> Neil: **In a parallel worlds theory, we can't know the relationship between consciousness and multiple realities.** Does your head hurt yet?
> Protagonist: Yes.
> Neil: Try to sleep.

Like the Protagonist, my head hurt too. While I think I got the gist of the "optimistically" part (that just by being there at that moment means that the Tenet team eventually stop the people in the future from triggering the algorithm and inverting the entropy of the world), I don't quite understand the "pessimistically" part.

Is Neil saying that there are possibly multiple realities, and they could be living in a reality where they failed to stop the people in the future from triggering the algorithm? If that was the case, they appear to not be affected by the triggered algorithm anyway as they are conscious and alive. I'm confused on how that's pessimistic.

What does Neil mean by "In a parallel worlds theory, we can't know the relationship between consciousness and multiple realities"?

Comment: It is literally *the worst case scenario*; something like : ***if there are infinite parallel worlds, it is highly possible that there's one world where people do not know/do not believe parallel worlds exist***.

Comment: Given that we don't the connection (if there is one) between parallel worlds and our consciousness (or subconsciousness), then how do we know we weren't already destroyed but just don't realise it yet because our minds haven't _comprehended_ it yet?

Comment: Perhaps our consciousness' are linked to some unknown parallel universe.

Comment: It probably has to due with conflicting interpretations of quantum physics. Generally in multiverse theories the wave function doesn't collapse because all the possibilities for the collapse are in their own universe.  Contrast that with a theory where only conscious observers cause collapse.  They don't mix. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Wigner_interpretation

Answer (score 1):

Parallel worlds theory or the Many Worlds Interpretation (MWI) of quantum mechanics posits that there are infinite worlds, or universes, all existing simultaneously where every possible permutation of events that could take place is taking place.

In the context of this particular exchange, Neil is suggesting that it’s possible when you “die” you wouldn’t know it because your consciousness could be redirected to another of those infinite universes that is nearly identical to the previous one you were existing in, with the exception being that you didn’t die.

Comment: I think it could also be a simpler comment that the mere fact that they were having conscious experiences of that reality doesn't mean that Sator won't succeed in "destroying" that reality and replacing it with a new, alternate reality. This needn't have anything to do with the issue of one's consciousness "transferring" from the destroyed reality to the new one.